# unable to write two database tables data to XML file using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch, xstream, spring-batch-admin

I'm liking the `Spring Batch` now gradually. I'm developing `Spring Batch` code which read two tables data (`Customer` and `Employee`) and writes to XML file. I developed code and when run my main() program I see empty file is coming. Why ?

customers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><customers></customers>
```

The code I developed for reference below:
Customer.java

```
public class Customer implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer customerNumber;
    private String customerName;
    private String contactLastName;
    private String contactFirstName;
    private String phone;
    private String addressLine1;
    private String addressLine2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String postalCode;
    private String country;
    private Integer salesRepEmployeeNumber;
    private Double creditLimit;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer employeeNumber;
    private String lastName;
    private String firstName;
    private String extension;
    private String email;
    private String officeCode;
    private Integer reportsTo;
    private String jobTitle;
    // setters and getters
}
```

xml-jdbc-composite-item-reader-job.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml" />

    <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="jobLauncher"  class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Step will need a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


    <!-- =========================================================== -->    
    <job id="compositeJdbcReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep" next="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader1" writer="itemWriter1" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>

        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemWriter2" writer="itemWriter2" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>



    <!-- ========== ItemReader =============== -->
    <bean id="itemReader1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="saveState" value="true" />

        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[ ${select.sql.customers} ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.common.batch.mapper.CustomerMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="itemReader2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="saveState" value="true" />

        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[ ${select.sql.employees} ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.common.batch.mapper.EmployeeMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- ItemWritter -->
    <bean id="itemWriter1" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:xml/customers.xml" />

        <property name="marshaller" ref="customerUnmarshaller" />

        <property name="rootTagName" value="customers" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemWriter2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:xml/customers.xml" />

        <property name="marshaller" ref="employeeUnmarshaller" />

        <property name="rootTagName" value="employees" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ======= Employee Unmarshaller ======== -->
    <bean id="employeeUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="employee" value="com.common.batch.model.Employee" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <!-- ======= Customer Unmarshaller ======== -->
    <bean id="customerUnmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="customer" value="com.common.batch.model.Customer" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="itemCustomerProcessor" class="com.common.batch.processor.CustomerProcessor" />
    <bean id="itemEmployeeProcessor" class="com.common.batch.processor.EmployeeProcessor" />
</beans>
```

CompositeXMLMain.java

```
public class CompositeXMLMain {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("composite/xml-jdbc-composite-item-reader-job.xml");

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("compositeJdbcReaderJob");

        JobExecution execution;
        try {
            execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Job Exit Status : "+ execution.getStatus());

        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException
                | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done !!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had make a small mistake, in order to fix the issue, simply need to change `itemWriter2` to `itemReader2`

```
 <job id="compositeJdbcReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep" next="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader1" writer="itemWriter1" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>

        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemWriter2" writer="itemWriter2" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
```

to

```
 <job id="compositeJdbcReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep" next="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader1" writer="itemWriter1" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>

        <step id="compositeJdbcReaderStep2">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="itemReader2" writer="itemWriter2" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
```